# Tensorflow error with 'Graph execution error' and ''

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

When i want to start training i have error. Now i update tensor flow to verion 2.15.0 and my Python 3.11. This is my code:

```
import pathlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#import PIL
import tensorflow as tf

dataset_lib = pathlib.Path("dataset/")
image_count = len(list(dataset_lib.glob("*/*.jpg")))
print(f"Images: {image_count}")

batch_size = 32
img_width = 180
img_height = 180

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    dataset_lib,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='training',
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size
)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    dataset_lib,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='validation',
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size
)

class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(f"Class names: {class_names}")

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

num_classes = len(class_names)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),

    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal", input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomContrast(0.2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),

    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),

    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

epochs = 10
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=epochs
)
```

And my error:

```
File "d:\Projects\Python\science-project\training.py", line 77, in <module>
    history = model.fit(
              ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node decode_image/DecodeImage defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required.
         [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2557]
2023-11-18 13:10:25.783963: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/cache_dataset_ops.cc:858] The calling iterator did not fully read the dataset being cached. In order to avoid unexpected truncation of the dataset, the partially cached contents of the dataset  will be discarded. This can happen if you have an input pipeline similar to `dataset.cache().take(k).repeat()`. You should use `dataset.take(k).cache().repeat()` instead.
```

I try to solve this problem, for example tit said `Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required`, i change format to .png but problem not changed (my format is .jpg).